# Base64 Image not displaying in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, base64, gatsby

Just fired up my first project in Gatsby. I followed the guide here for loading images https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/importing-assets-into-files/

src/components/header.js

```
import logo from "../images/logo-color.png";

const Header = () => (
  <Link to="/">
    <img src={logo} alt="" />
  </Link>
);
```

As mentioned in the docs `To reduce the number of requests to the server, importing images that are less than 10,000 bytes returns a data URI instead of a path.` And inside the `src` of my image when I inspect the page I see the base64 code but the image is broken on the page?

Is there specific rules to how it converts these images? When I change the logo import to one of the images that come default with the new project those ones do load but they load the actual src path and are not encoded since I assume they are larger files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty random but it turns out that when I copied all the images I wanted to use into the images directory they were just aliases. In MacOS you can tell in Finder there is a little arrow on the icon beside the file. Doubt anyone will ever have this problem but it took me a good 6 hours to figure out...